# Alguém sabe como inserir nomes em ordem alfabética em um vetor c++?

Tags: c++

Fiz esse código mas não funciona direito, insere em ordem alfabética ao contrário.

```
void inserirNomeNaLista(vector<string> &lista)
{
    vector<string>::iterator itr;
    string nome;
    cout << "Digite o nome para ser inserido na lista: ";
    cin >> nome;

    if (lista.size() == 0)
    {
        lista.push_back(nome);
    }
    else
    {
        for (itr = lista.begin(); itr != lista.end(); itr++)
        {
            if (*itr > nome)
            {
                lista.insert(itr, nome);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem certeza que ele está inserindo sempre ao contrário? O seu `break` está fora do bloco do `if (*itr > nome)` (ao invés de estar dentro dele), o que faz com que ele insira apenas se a nova string for menor ou igual à string do primeiro elemento do vetor. Por causa do `break`, o laço sempre se encerra após a primeira interação.

Answer (score 5):

Se você planeja que sua lista seja ordenada, a forma mais simples de fazer isso é usar diretamente um [`std::set`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), que é ordenado e não permite duplicatas. O código fica assim:

```
std::set<std::string> nomes;
nomes.insert("Pedro");
nomes.insert("Amanda");
nomes.insert("Maria");

for (auto& nome : nomes)
    std::cout << nome << std::endl; // Amanda, Maria, Pedro
```

[**(coliru)**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8207eef3cd876cfe)

No entanto, se você quer se manter usando o [`std::vector`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), pode procurar pela posição se inserção usando o [`std::lower_bound`](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). Mas note que essa função só funciona corretamente em listas já ordenadas ([busca binária](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesquisa_bin%C3%A1ria)). Assim:

```
void sortedInsert(std::vector<std::string>& vec, std::string value) {
    auto it = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
    vec.insert(it, std::move(value));
}

std::vector<std::string> nomes;
sortedInsert(nomes, "Pedro");
sortedInsert(nomes, "Amanda");
sortedInsert(nomes, "Maria");

for (auto& nome : nomes)
    std::cout << nome << std::endl; // Amanda, Maria, Pedro
```

[**(coliru)**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b04af6c409364939)
Com um pouco de templates a mais: [**(coliru)**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14dbabbc08e64343)

Answer (score 4):

Sugiro você dar uma estudada nos algoritmos padrão da STL. Para resolver este exato problema seu já existe o [`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

```
#include <algorithm>

void inserirNomeNaLista(std::vector<string> &lista)
{
  std::string nome;
  std::cout << "Digite o nome para ser inserido na lista: ";
  std::cin >> nome;

  typedef std::vector<std::string>::iterator VecIter;
  VecIter itr = std::lower_bound(lista.begin(), lista.end(), nome);    
  lista.insert(itr, nome);
}
```

Ele pesquisa em um sequência (par de iteradores) o ponto onde se deve inserir um item para que a sequência fique em ordem crescente. Ele é eficiente, pois executa busca binária, mas só funciona se a sequência **estiver sempre ordenada**. Mas se você só usar ele para inserir elementos em um `vector` não há problema, pois neste caso as inserções sempre serão em ordem.

---

Agora se isto for um exercício, e você não puder utilizar os algoritmos padrão, acredito que seu erro seja a posição do `break`, como já explicado n[o comentário do Luiz Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6966/alguem-sabe-como-inserir-nomes-em-ordem-alfabetica-em-um-vetor-c#comment11669_6966).

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, a STL já disponibiliza o método sort() pra você. Ele analisa lexicograficamente as strings e as ordena. Aí vai um exemplo.

```
#include <algorithm> //Para o sort()
#include <iostream> //Para o cout
#include <vector>  //Para o vector<>()
#include <string> //Para a string

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("bac"); v.push_back("abc"); v.push_back("cab"); v.push_back("cba");
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Vale notar que para vectors essa resposta é a mais eficiente se for inserir todas as string de uma única vez (sendo que a lista não estará ordenada entre as inserções). Essa é `O(nlogn)` enquanto que a outra (usando `std::lower_bound`) é `O(n²)` em worse case. No caso de usar o `std::set`, a complexidade será `O(nlogn)`, mas a lista estará sempre ordenada (melhor).

Comment: Perfeito. Obviamente é, de fato, inviável ordenar os vetores a cada inserção. Como você disse, é mais proveitoso ordenar no final das inserções ou usar um std::set.